# What is the Fractional Functional Central Limit theorem?

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

What is the statement of the "Fractional Functional Central Limit theorem (FFCLT)"? There is a  Functional Central Limit Theorem, also called Donsker's theorem. Which has a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) .

I presume that FFCLT is connected to the above one, but I am not certain. The reason I am interested in this is that it is invoked in a paper without a clear reference to it, suggesting that the FFCLT is at least somewhat well known.

Comment: Do you have a link to the paper?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in the question. I have forgotten that (the question is two years old).